# autoreconf -i not running recursively with AX_SUBDIRS_CONFIGURE

Tags: autotools

I am using autotools to generate a `configure` file to compile a C project called `hello`, whose compilation depends on the successful compilation of a library subdirectory. The subdirectory is called `the_subdir` and generates a library called `lib_mytest.a`.

The subdirectory project (`the_subdir`) may receive a flag called `--enable-other`. If it does not receive this flag, it creates the library(`lib_mytest.a`) by compiling a C file called `myfile.c`, if it does receive this flag, the library is generated with C file `myfile_other.c`. In both cases `lib_mytest.a` is generated, but they behave differently.

Project hello **needs** to use the version of `lib_mytest.a` that uses the special flag(`--enable-other`), so a Makefile for `hello` would have to recursively make the lib by passing the special `--enable-other` flag. I am trying to achieve this through autotools. Upon reading the documentation, I understand that I need to use the [`AX_SUBDIRS_CONFIGURE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_subdirs_configure.html) command, which emulates `AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS`, but allows us to run automake recursively by passing specific flags to specific subdirectories.

To do this, I set up the project the following way. Directory `hello` has the tree structure and files stated below.

The issue: When I run `autoreconf -i` on the root directory to generate the `./configure` file, the subdirectory configure file (`the_subdir/configure`) is **not** generated, and then when I run `./configure`, I get a warning saying that `the_subdir/configure` does not exist. This is unlike the behavior of `AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS`, which **does** create the configure subdirs when `autoreconf -i` is run. This does not agree with the fact that `AX_SUBDIRS_CONFIGURE` is supposed to emulate the behavior of `AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS`. If I run `autoreconf -i` in both the root directory and inside `the_subdir`, then `./configure` runs normally, running the checks both for the root and subdirectory. This, however, feels like a hack, since I find it unlikely that I need to automake all subdirectories on a larger project. What would be the correct syntax to attain both (1) passing the `--enable-other` flag to my subdirectory and (2) generating all `configure` files for my subdirectories with one call of `autoreconf -i` (or any other command) in the root?

This is the tree structure of this example project (the m4 and C files are not relevant to the problem I think?)

```
├── configure.ac
├── m4
│   ├── ax_configure_args.m4
│   └── ax_subdirs_configure.m4
├── main.c
├── Makefile.am
└── the_subdir
    ├── configure.ac
    ├── Makefile.am
    ├── mytest.c
    ├── mytest.h
    ├── mytest_other.c
    └── mytest_other.h
```

the root `configure.ac` has the following content:

```
AC_INIT([Tutorial Program], 1.0)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])
AC_PROG_CC
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])

dnl here we compare AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS with
dnl AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS([the_subdir])
AX_SUBDIRS_CONFIGURE([the_subdir], [--enable-other])

AC_CONFIG_FILES(Makefile)
AC_OUTPUT
```

the root `Makefile.am`:

```
SUBDIRS := the_subdir                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

bin_PROGRAMS = prog
prog_SOURCES = main.c

LDADD = the_subdir/lib_mytest.a
```

`the_subdir/configure.ac`:

```
AC_INIT([Subdir Program], 1.0)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])
AC_PROG_CC

AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([mytest.h])

AM_PROG_AR
AC_PROG_RANLIB

dnl the line breaks in this message are intended
other_fail_msg="

Failed to locate OtherLib on your system.
"

AC_ARG_ENABLE([other],
  [AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-other], [Enable OtherLib @<:@no@:>@])],
  [enable_other=yes], [enable_other=no])
dnl AS_IF([test "x$enable_other" = "xyes"],
dnl   [AC_CHECK_LIB([other], [other_version], [], [AC_MSG_FAILURE([$other_fail_msg])])])
AM_CONDITIONAL([ENABLE_OTHER], [test "x$enable_other" = "xyes"])

AC_CONFIG_FILES(Makefile)
AC_OUTPUT
```

`the_subdir/Makefile.am`:

```
lib_LIBRARIES = lib_mytest.a                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

lib_mytest_a_SOURCES = mytest.c

if ENABLE_OTHER
lib_mytest_a_SOURCES += mytest_other.c
endif

include_HEADERS = mytest.h

if ENABLE_OTHER
lib_mytest_a_SOURCES += mytest_other.h
endif
```

This is what I get when running `autoreconf -v -i` (note that it does not recurse into the subdirectory):

```
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal 
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Autoheader
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --no-force
configure.ac:3: installing './compile'
configure.ac:2: installing './install-sh'
configure.ac:2: installing './missing'
Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
autoreconf: Leaving directory `.'
```

And this is the output of `./configure`, which complains about no ./configure in `the_subdir`:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
=== configuring in the_subdir (/home/sena/hello/the_subdir)
configure: WARNING: no configuration information is in the_subdir
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: executing depfiles commands
```

but then if I also run `autoreconf -i` in the subdir then run `./configure` in root, everything goes well:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
=== configuring in the_subdir (/home/sena/hello/the_subdir)
configure: running /bin/bash ./configure '--prefix=/home/sena/hello' --disable-option-checking  '--enable-other' '--srcdir=.' --cache-file=
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for ar... ar
checking the archiver (ar) interface... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: executing depfiles commands
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: executing depfiles commands
```

Any help on the correct way to do this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any chance you managed to solve this yourself? I’m having the same issue and it’s driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

`AX_SUBDIRS_CONFIGURE` is not part of Autoconf (which the `AX_` prefix tells you).  It can be obtained from the GNU-hosted Autoconf Archive, but the macro itself is not owned or maintained by GNU or the Autoconf developers.  Accordingly, the `autoreconf` tool of Autoconf does not attribute any special significance to that macro or give it the kind of special treatment that it gives `AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS`.  To the extent that the former's documentation suggests otherwise, that documentation is flawed.

One alternative would be to use `AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS` instead, and rely on passing `--enable-other` to the top-level `configure` script, which it will then forward to the (every) sub-configure.  You could provide a wrapper script for the top-level `configure` that does this automatically, so as to reduce the likelihood of a misconfiguration arising from failing to specify that flag.

Another alternative would be (again) to use `AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS`, and to rely on this detail of its behavior:

> If a given dir contains `configure.gnu`, it is run instead of `configure`.

([Autoconf manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.70/autoconf.html#Subdirectories))

Although ...

> This is for packages that might use a non-Autoconf script `Configure`,
> which can’t be called through a wrapper `configure` since it would be
> the same file on case-insensitive file systems.

... you can also use it for your purposes by dropping in a `configure.gnu` like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec "${0%.gnu}" --enable-other "$@"
```

The main other alternative is to be satisfied with `autoreconf` not recursing into the subdirectory.  Depending on the specific circumstances, that could be considered a feature rather than a bug.

In this case, the description of the issue suggests that Autotools-built build-system components are not already available in the subdirectory, but why should that actually be?  Source distributions of Autotools-based projects should include already-built autotooling, such that people who merely want to build the project don't need to have the Autotools themselves at all.  That would apply just as well if you distribute a third-party project inside your own source distribution.

Under some circumstances, it might also be a viable option to merge the subproject into the main project, so that it no longer has a separate configuration script to worry about.

Comment: So you’re saying that `AX_SUBDIRS_CONFIGURE` simply does not work, at all? — Regarding your last alternative, that’s unfortunately not applicable in all situations, e.g. when building a project with third-party dependencies included as Git submodules. A dirty workaround is to have a top-level build script which performs the correct invocation, but of course it would be nicer if the top-level project could use autotools without the need for such custom script wrappers.

Comment: No, @KonradRudolph, I am saying that it does not serve the particular usage the question asks about, centered on the `autoreconf` utility.  That case is not the main point of `AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS`, either.  These macros both are primarily about the behavior of the generated `configure` scripts, not so much about the `autoconf`, `automake`, `autoreconf`, *etc* tools.

Comment: Ah, thanks. In my view these two uses are fairly tightly intertwined; without `autoconf`, no `configure` script, after all.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I would agree with "dependent", but "intertwined" suggests a different usage model than the Autotools are designed for.  Running `autoreconf` is an activity for project developers / maintainers, somewhat uncommonly performed once the built system has been set up.  Everyone else should get already-built autotooling, including in particular a `configure` script, and should not need to run the autotools.  The tarball produced by `make dist` will provide that, for example.

Comment: I recognize that in recent years an idea has taken hold in some places that `configure`, `Makefile.in`, and similar should be considered built files and therefore not distributed -- especially where revision-control systems are pressed into service as distribution mechanisms -- but this approach is fraught with more problems than just requiring extra tools to build the software.